# I updated this question. Is this good enough to be undeleted?

Tags: support

https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13388/need-laptop-tablet

The original question didn't have enough detail. What about now?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, thanks! I edited the title to be a bit more detailed, and I removed the last line asking for a website to compare specs because that's not something we can recommend here. It's now undeleted and reopened.